# How do I split stacked materials in equal stacks on the crafting table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a single large stack of a material. It's quite difficult to go "gather" four times if I need four of one object. Isn't there some way for me to break up a stack in an equal amount of pieces?

Answer (score 6):

There is a different way of dropping equal amounts of items into a crafting table that you haven't mentioned in your answer:

With a selected stack of material, hold down left click and 'draw' the shape you want.  This will distribute the stack evenly in that shape.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to split the stack:

1. Right click the stack to pick up half of it.
2. Right click whilst holding a stack to only drop one of whatever item you're holding.

Answer (score 0):

To split a stack in half, right click it. To put an even amount of something in a crafting table or chest or your inventory, hold left click on the stack and drag the stack in the shape you want it to be. If you drag the stack over a slot you already placed an item in, it will not affect the slot of items.